# Android ListView's item's Image background color does not change

Tags: java, android, listview, kotlin

I have some Android app, which is mixture of [Java](https://www.java.com/en/) and [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) and inside this app I have [Listview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html), which contains available `WiFi` networks. When I select element of this `ListView`, [Dialog](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) pops up asking for user intervention, which is all ok so far. Now, when I press [Submit button](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html), this `Dialog` hides and the selected `ListView`'s item's [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) should get [Steelblue](http://www.color-hex.com/color/4682b4) color, but it does not:

```
    dialog.buttonNewGroup.setOnClickListener { _: View? ->
        val newGroupDialog: MaterialDialog = MaterialDialog.Builder(this@AddDevicesActivity)
                .title(R.string.new_group_dialog_title)
                .content(R.string.new_group_dialog_content)
                .inputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
                        + InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL
                        + InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT + InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE + InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES)
                .inputRange(1, 32)
                .input(R.string.group_name, 0, false, { _, _ -> })
                .negativeText(R.string.cancel)
                .positiveText(R.string.submit)
                .onPositive { dialog, _ ->
                    // Add new group to database
                    mDb.addGroup(VentGroup(dialog.inputEditText?.text.toString()))
                    // Get refreshed list of the groups
                    mGroups.clear()
                    mDb.getGroups().toCollection(mGroups)
                    mGroupsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    this@AddDevicesActivity.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("0xff4682b4"))    // IMAGE BACKGROUND DOES NOT CHANGE TO "Steelblue" color
                }
                .build()
        newGroupDialog.show()
    }
```

I've added breakpoint in this part of code and it **DOES GETS** executed, however, the `background` of `ImageView` does not change. Why?

P.S.: I am new to `Kotlin` and rather new in `Android/Java` and I ask for a little understanding before downvoting, since I am aware there must be some dumb mistake behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi KernelPanic try ,

```
(dialog.actiivty as AddDevicesActivity).imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("0xff4682br"))
```